# How can I concatenate and integer with a string?

Tags: string, concatenation

I'm receiving an error when I try to concatenate weight_kg with a string "kilograms". I want the numerical output of weight_kg followed by the string "kilograms". E.g. '50 kilograms'.

I've tried to convert weight_kg as a string so I can concatenate it to the string "kilograms"

```
weight_lbs = input("Weight (lbs): ")
weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.45
print(weight_kg)

print(weight_kg) + str("kilograms")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

> print(weight_kg) + str("kilograms")

you were trying to add the return value of a `print()` (which is a `NoneType`) to a `string`. They can't be added together.

You might want something like this:

`print( str(weight_kg) + "kilograms" )`

which converts `weight_kg` to `string` first then concatenates and prints the result out.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(str(weight_kg)+"kilograms")
```

no need to cast a string again to string,
and use str(object) to case object to str (like integer at your case)
and print function syntax is `print("things to be printed <must be inside the () of the print func>")`
to concatenate a 2 strings just `str3=str_1+str_2`
so according to this all :

```
print(str(weight_kg)+"kilograms")
```